# mysql VARBINARY datatype is not working while alter table column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    mysql> ALTER TABLE googly MODIFY Data VARBINARY;
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    mysql>
```

I am trying to alter my mysql database column using above query.
But it is giving me above error.

The reason i am using VARBINARY instead of BINARY is my data is too long.

BINARY giving me below error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'Data' at row 1
```

Is there any way to fix it ?

Please take a look.

Comment: Try supplying a length to the varbinary

Comment: `varbinary` is not *longer* than `binary`. `varbinary` is *[allowed to be shorter than specified](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)* whereas `binary` is not. Neither can be longer than specified.